# ¿Como agrupar objetos de arrays que estos tengan una coincidencia?

Tags: array, angular, typescript

Gracias por la molestia antes que nada.

Necesito agrupar objetos de varios array que tienen de coincidencia un Id.

Datos:

```
[
 0:{id: 2, obj: {1,2}},
 1:{id: 2, obj: {1,3}},
 2:{id: 3, obj: {4,5,6}},
 3:{id: 2, obj: {1,7}}
]
```

Como resultado yo espero:

```
[
 0:{id: 2, obj: {1,2,1,3,1,7}},
 1:{id: 3, obj: {4,5,6}}
]
```

Lo eh intentado de muchas maneras, pero no logro conseguirlo, eh Sacado los id unicos, para hacerle un for pero nunca obtengo el resultado deseado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

en javascript hay una librería que ayuda mucho a la hora de manejar objetos o arreglos etc.

Se llama [Underscorejs](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), la librería tiene un método groupBy que te pudiera ayudar.

La manera de importar la seria

```
import * as _ from "underscore"
```

Espero que te pueda funcionar.